# Corrupted Bootcamp Parition lost in Disk Utility

Tags: macos, hard-drive, partitioning, boot-camp

My OSX Yosemite Mac had a partition of Win 8 that was corrupted and is not lost.

Now the original 500GB drive is only 200 and unable to use the 300GB corrupted Win drive. (see photos)

From other tutiorals, I was able to display this data, but have not been able to recover the lost 300 GB before I repartition the drive for Windows again.

Because I don't see the lost drive in Disk Utilites, I am not able to retore the partition like 99% of tuts suggest.

Please help!
[image]

Comment: 'lost corrupted'? Did you try to change it in any way from Windows itself? That will break it every time. Also, Disk Utility cannot handle Logical Volume Group drives [Core Storage], fixes need to be done from terminal. try http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/168723/i-think-i-messed-up-the-fusion-drive-on-my-1tb-imac-with-bootcamp/168744#168744 to get an idea what might be going on.

Comment: I have edited my post to read more a bit better. "corrupted and now is lost". My windows partition because corrupted because it was shut down during a windows update. Ill check link out now